# How to rotate label in the top of each bar in geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling on how can I rotate the label of count values in `geom_histogram`. I'd like to rotate the labels, that should be in the top of each bar. I'm using the following code:

Toy example:

```
ex_tfdp = data.frame(x=rnorm(1000,10,10))

ggplot(ex_tfdp) +
geom_histogram(aes(x = x), boundary = 0,binwidth = 5, color="black", fill="#FFC857")+
  stat_bin( geom="text", colour="black", size=3.5,
          aes(x = x,label=..count..), angle = 90, vjust = -1.5)+ 
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = .5),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position="bottom",
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

Any hint on how can I change the angle of these values and put them in the top of the each bar?

Comment: would be nice to have a reproducible example. also, it's not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. what do you mean by "rotate"?

Comment: I'd like to change the angle of the labels values.

Comment: and how would changing the angle would make them on top of their respective bars? seems that you want to adjust their vertical position?

Comment: I made a toy example...
I'd like to put the values in the top of each bar and change the angle of them (90º).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't have your data, but assuming it is similar to the following:

```r
set.seed(2)
my_data <- data.frame(measure = rexp(20000)^1.2 * 150)
```

Then you can correctly bin your data by switching to `geom_text` and using `stat = "bin"`. Then you can still pass `breaks` as an argument to the stat. This allows you to use the `geom_text` parameter `angle` to rotate 90 degrees. A bit of `hjust` and `vjust` tweaking then gets your labels right:

```
ggplot(my_data) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = measure), boundary = 0,
                 binwidth = 100, color="black", fill="#FFC857")+
   geom_text(stat = "bin", colour = "black", size = 3.5,
             breaks = seq(0,2100,100), hjust = -0.5,
            aes(x = measure, label=..count..), vjust = 0.5, angle = 90)+
         scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,2100,100), 
                            labels = seq(0,2100,100),
                            expand = expansion(add = c(0, 0))) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 15000)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = .5),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position="bottom",
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have simplified your example a bit:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

set.seed(15)
ex_tfdp = data.frame(x=rnorm(1000,10,10))

original.plot = ggplot(ex_tfdp) +
    geom_histogram(aes(x = x), boundary = 0,binwidth = 5, color="black", fill="#FFC857")+
    stat_bin( geom="text", colour="black", size=3.5,
              aes(x = x,label=..count..), angle = 90, vjust = -1.5)

new.plot = ggplot(ex_tfdp) +
    geom_histogram(aes(x = x), boundary = 0, binwidth = 5)+ ylim(c(0, 220)) +
    stat_bin( geom="text", colour="black", size=3.5,
              aes(x = x,label=..count..), angle = 90, boundary = 0, binwidth = 5, hjust = -.5)

grid.arrange(original.plot, new.plot, ncol=2)
```

[image]

The key here is to keep the `boundary = 0` and `binwidth = 5` when adding the `stat_bin` layer.